# What are the "Qualities of the Buddha"?

Tags: the-buddha

What is meant by the phrase the "qualities of the Buddha"? Are these qualities to which unenlightened people can aspire or do these qualities emerge only upon enlightenment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following are the 9 qualities of the Buddha one should get inspiration and try to develop:

> Buddho – Awakened
>
> Sammasambuddho – Perfectly self-awakened
>
> Vijja-carana-sampano – Endowed with higher knowledge and ideal conduct.
>
> Sugato – Well-gone or Well-spoken.
>
> Lokavidu – Wise in the knowledge of the many worlds.
>
> Anuttaro Purisa-damma-sarathi – Unexcelled trainer of untrained people.
>
> Satthadeva-Manussanam – Teacher of gods and humans.
>
> Bhagavathi – The Blessed one
>
> Araham – Worthy of homage. An Arahant is "one with taints destroyed, who has lived the holy life, done what had to be done, laid down the burden, reached the true goal, destroyed the fetters of being, and is completely liberated through final knowledge."

(Sourced from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha#Nine_virtues)

Comment: Sir, I had wrote a few words (that could be appeared as an another question, but while doing that I got my answer. Thank you for providing the missing link. You own the center of my regards.

Comment: Good that this is of help.

Answer (score 1):

I remember vaguely about one sutta, A Prince heard about Buddha's great reputation and he was skeptical. He wanted to investigate that himself so he sent his most trusted advisor to camp out near jeta grove to report back his opinion and what he saw in buddha.  The advisor camped out for seven months to make sure he saw the true buddha not just an act.

And the report contained mostly about buddha's demeanors ...
 Such as buddha would walk with his eyes  downward at the groud at a full length of a bamboo tree (about 50 feet).
Buddha would turn his entire body to look at something to his left or right (not just turning his head).
His shoulders would not sway as he walked.
He would not swing his arms as he walked.
He would step his right foot out first when he started to go somewhere. 
His body would not go up and down as he walked.
When he sit to teach dhama or to eat, he would not rest his back on a backrest.
He would not sit with one knee up.
His robe was not too tight or too loose.
He would speak just loud enough for all his audience to hear and not beyond..etc.
Many other things in that report.   It gives us some ideas to imagine what buddha was like in those time.
But def the 9 Qualities in the first answer is something a buddhist has to learn.

Could anyone please let me know if you know this sutta?   Thanks

Comment: Hi Dean: welcome to the site. Would you mind reposting what you wrote as a new separate question, using the [Ask a Question](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and assigning tags to the question like [tag:the-buddha] and [tag:reference-request]? I ask because I think that other people are more likely to see your question and maybe answer it if you post as a new question.

Comment: hi Chris.  thanks for kind words.  reference request is a very good place to post it.   thanks

Answer (score -1):

"What are the “Qualities of the Buddha”?"

Qualities of 'Bhagava Araham Sammasambuddho' is infinite and cannot be known by any human being.

Please see Sampasadaniya Sutta of Digha Nikaya.

The expression "qualities of the Buddha" belong to English Buddhism. Oxford Dictionaries define the 'the Buddha' as a historical figure that lived about 25 centuries ago-his birth date or the date of death is unknown.

However, the Tipitaka published by the Pali Text Society refer to a Bhagava Araham Sammasambuddho, in the Sutta and Vinaya Pitakas. Most of the words in the two Pitakas are utterences of Bhagava; the word means a spiritual teacher.

Human beings who have no clue to even the physical form of Bhagava, what would they know about his mind?